# How to loop through a vector of URLs and scrape some basic tags from each

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to loop through a list of URLs and scrape some data from each link.  Here is my code.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import webbrowser
import requests

url_list = ['https://corp-intranet.com/admin/graph?dag_id=emm1_daily_legacy',
'https://corp-intranet.com/admin/graph?dag_id=emm1_daily_legacy_history']

for link in url_list:
    File = webbrowser.open(link)
    File = requests.get(link)
    data = File.text
    soup = bs(data, "lxml")
    tspans = soup.find_all("tspan")
    tspans
```

I think this is pretty close, but I'm getting nothing for the 'tspans' variable.  I get no error; 'tspans' just shows [].

This is an internal corporate intranet, so I can't share the exact details, but I think it's just a matter of grabbing all the HTML elements named 'tspans' and writing all of them to a text file or a CSV file.  That's my ultimate goal.  I want to collate everything into a large list and write it all to a file.

As an aside, I was going to use Selenium to log into this site, which requires creds, but it seem like the code I'm testing now allows you you open new tabs on a browser, and everything loads up fine, if you are already logged in.  Is this the best practice, or should I use the full login creds + Selenium?  I'm just trying to keep things simple.

Comment: __soup__ variable is not empty? pages have something "tspan"?

Comment: Does your intranet require credentials? Ex: `requests.get('https://api.github.com/user', auth=HTTPBasicAuth('user', 'pass'))`

Comment: I believe the easiest solution is to get the ```request.get(link)```, save it, and handle with it later. Maybe write a test which mocks the request and just analyses the page